# When using the keyboard library, find the coordinates of the cycle that appears on the screen and make a left mouse click with pyautogui

Tags: python, oop, keyboard, pyautogui

In this problem, the keyboard.press("tab"), a circle appears in the application I am working on. Then I want to find the coordinates of this circle and make a left click with the mouse, but my code does not work. Where could I have made a mistake. ?

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

def monsterclick():
    keyboard.press("tab")
    x, y = pyautogui.position("tab")

while True:
      monsterclick()
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

With `pyautogui.position` you are saving the current cursor's x and y, you never located the circle on the screen. You can use `pyautogui.click('circle.png')` to locate and click the image you provided as argument:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

def monsterclick():
    keyboard.press("tab")
    # This will locate and click the circle. If the circle is not found it will return none
    x, y = pyautogui.click('circle.png')

while True:
      monsterclick()
      break
```